# NLP Paragraph Level Predictions vs Doc Level Predictions? What Strategy to deploy

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, tf-idf, doc2vec

currently wanted to understand which model an approach I am incorporating for model development, I currently have a TF-IDF NLP model that reads in paragraphs for a document and makes a prediction based upon how many paragraphs scored a 1 label with that paragraph.

I am not sure if that is correct form of logic, should I just go with an document level model? what are the benefits and trade-offs of predicting at a paragraph level and rolling it up into a total prediction for the document vs just classifying the document itself.

Any Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You should try both ways against your data & goals, and measure which one works better in your actual usage scenario. (There's no general answer others can give you for all domains/data-sources/prediction-goals/etc – "what's better" in your case has to be answered via experiments/tinkering on the exact data/goals of your case.)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what problem you are trying to solve and the nature of your data.

If in one document different parts can be classified differently, it's better to make a prediction by paragraphs or even sentences. For example - quite often, the customer can be happy with one part of the product/item (the first sentence is positive). And be dissatisfied with another part of the product/item (the second sentence has a negative sentiment).

Or, if the document is entirely related to a specific topic, you can make a prediction using the entire text.

In the end, these are just assumptions. Hold out a test subset and validate your model for both cases.

Comment: Thank you for this, my question is with that logic at the paragraph level, if i predict a document classification by doing some type of roll up of paragraphs, using the most number of paragraph classification per document, lets say there are 50 paragraph's labeled fruit, if classify that document as fruit, is that statistically correct? the models I incorporated are getting good f1 scores 90+ based upon this roll up logic however i am wondering if that is correct? @gojomo

Comment: what do you think of this as well